# How do I get the values from a list box converted correctly as variables

Tags: c#, listbox

Im very new to c# and coding in general. For my class I need to get the average, lowest, and highest number out of a list box. Im just trying to get all the numbers out and add them all together and divide them simply. I understand its not efficient but I need to understand it first.

```
private void button1_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double firstValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[0];
    double secondValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[1];
    double thirdValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[2];
    double fourthValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[3];
    double fifthValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[4];
    double sixthValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[5];
    double seventhValue = (double)listBox_Values.Items[6];

    double average = 0;

    average = firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue + fourthValue + fifthValue + sixthValue + seventhValue / 7;
    textBox_Average.Text = average.ToString();
}
```

Comment: 1. Use parentheses. 2. Use array/collection. 3. Use loop.

Comment: note that `A + B + C / D` is equivalent to `A + B + (C / D)`. Use parenthesis, like in regular math

Comment: What if you don't have 7 values, but 8? 6? N? It's a good use case for loops.

Comment: Since this is working, I think this question would rather fit [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your list of numbers and then divide by the number of list items:

```
int total = 0;
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
{
    total += Convert.ToInt32(item);
}
int average = total / listBox1.Items.Count;
```

Comment: Thanks @Cid I added a more traditional example